# How to emulate bash's "ulimit -u" command using C and system calls?

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls

I was given the task of writing a program  that determines the maximum number of  processes a user can have, just like the bash's  "ulimit -u" built-in command  but **using system calls and C**. Any hint as to how achieve this?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ulimit` builtin is just an interface to the `getrlimit` and `setrlimit` functions.

See the [getrlimit, setrlimit man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html).

In particular, you are interested in the `RLIMIT_NPROC` resource.